# Create binary tree of fixed size

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary tree. Only thing I am given is the number of the nodes in the tree. The first thing popped in to my head is to use an index(**BFS order**) to keep the track of the number of total nodes, then use a recursive definition. Here is my pseudocode to do that.

```
N = 10         //binary tree total node count
i = 0          //global integer
function()
    if i > N
        return True

    create node i
    i = i + 1
    function(i) //left
    i = i + 1
    function(i) //right
```

I have to use a global variable in this definition which makes me feel like maybe I am violating recursion rules. Is there a better way to do what I do, if this is the way, can it be improved ?

**Note:** I am asking about the theoretical method, not the code.

**Edit:** I just realized this method fails. I am open for suggestions.

**Clarification:** The requirement for this tree is not to add an element to a depth, if the previous depth is not filled with nodes(all nodes have 2 children), pardon me for not mentioning this before, as for the stack I mentioned in the comments, it has nothing to do with the question, just the regular way of traversing trees iteratively.

Comment: The question doesn't say you need to generate the tree recursively; maybe you misunderstood the question. As for the generated tree: it's basically a linked list, since only left childs will be created. As for `i`: your code isn't correct, but it's already half-way to a solution without the global variable. You've `function` defined without parameter, yet use it with `i` as parameter...

Comment: @Paul I chose to use recursion for learning purposes. But iterative method is also appliable, need to define a stack in the program.

Comment: You should clarify what you actually want. Especially: what are the requirements for the tree? Your algorithm creates a perfectly fine tree, apart from the fact that the tree would contain `N + 1` nodes. And what does this question have to do with a stack?

Comment: @Paul Please check the edit.

Comment: alright. I'll post a solution

Answer (score 2):

A tree consists of three elements if defined recursively:

- a root node
- a left subtree, which is a tree itself
- a right subtree, which is a tree itself

all of these may be `NULL`.

Now we can distribute the numbers in a range `[a, b]` into a tree in the following manner:

- root contains `(a + b) / 2`
- left subtree is built of range `[a, (a + b) / 2 - 1]` recursively
- right subtree is built of the range `[(a + b) / 2 + 1, b]` recursively

A range with higher start than end may be considered as empty and results in a node being `NULL`. This distribution ensures that the left and right subtree differ at most by 1 in size and that each level is entirely filled up, before another level is getting filled.

E.g.:

```
N = 6
                                  [0, 5]

                 [0, 1]              2                  [3, 5]

         [0]        1        []               [3]          4         [5]

 []       0     []                      []     3      []        []    5    []
```

In addition this algorithm builds a BST (actually this basically the "reverse" of a binary search). Now for the algorithm itself:

```
function(a, b):
    if b < a: return NULL

    n = create node (a + b) / 2
    n.left = function(a, (a + b) / 2 - 1)
    n.right = function((a + b) / 2 + 1, b)

    return n
```

The tree can be generated by calling:

```
function(1, N)
```

Alternatively any other parameters `a` and `b` should work, where `a + N - 1 = b` holds. The two parameters represent the range (both inclusive) which should be held by the tree.

Comment: Damn this is advanced. Is there a name for the method you used, using two numbers to keep track of the index ?

Comment: @Rockybilly well, those two numbers are just used to represent a range. I doubt there's a specific name for that, since it's just a way of data-representation. And it just comes to my mind: I forgot how to initially call the method to create the tree. I'll edit